# A quando risale l’espressione “raga”?

Tags: word-usage

L’espressione raga, come suggerisce il dizionario Garzanti si riferisce a:

> (fam.) forma abbreviata di ragazzo; si usa soprattutto al vocativo: *ehi raga, ci schiodiamo?*

aggiungerei che viene usata anche come forma abbreviata di *ragazza* e soprattutto di *ragazzi*.

Essendo un’espressione molto comune entrata ormai anche nei dizionari della lingua italiana, mi chiedo a quando risale. Anni ‘90 o inizio duemila? O forse prima ancora.

Qualcuno riesce a documentare i primi utilizzi di questa parola?

Comment: Ho provato a guardare su Google Ngrams, ma purtroppo quasi tutti i risultati sono sigle, cognomi e [questo raga](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raga), per cui è difficile estrarre dei dati in mezzo a tutto il rumore.

Comment: @Denis - sì, avevo controllato anch’io ma senza esito. Sicuramente l’espressione è nata inizialmente nel linguaggio dei giovani. Forse qualcuno l’ha a suo tempo ripresa in qualche libro o articolo del periodo.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Io stessa avevo una collega di lavoro chiamata Raga di cognome.

Answer (score 4):

Spero che qualcun altro dia una risposta più compiuta, ma intanto ho due dati.

Lo Zingarelli 2019, che per ogni lemma riporta un anno (o secolo, per le parole più antiche) di prima attestazione, per “raga” in questo senso:

> nel linguaggio giovanile, abbreviazione di ‘ragazzo’, ‘ragazzi’ o ‘ragazza’, ‘ragazze’

dà un generico “av. 1963” (cioè prima del 1963): evidentemente i lessicografi hanno fonti certe per il 1963, ma sono al corrente di altre precedenti di difficile datazione.

*Scrostati gaggio! Dizionario storico dei linguaggi giovanili* di Renzo Ambrogio e Giovanni Casalegno non dà una datazione dei lemmi, ma si può ricavare un terminus ante quem dagli esempi riportati, il primo dei quali è

> Un tot dei raga sono in attesa della tregua giù in strada, scena che non quadra perché il sole non scalda.

dalla canzone “Guerra e pace” dell'album *107 elementi* di Neffa, del 1997. Altri esempi, da Rossana Campo, Carlo Lucarelli e altri, sono della fine degli anni '90 e dei primi anni 2000 (il dizionario stesso è del 2004).

Quindi negli anni '90 l'uso di “raga” è già pressoché “mainstream”, ma la datazione data dallo Zingarelli è molto precedente, e sarebbe interessante trovare quali siano i testi degli anni '60 in cui compare “raga”.